# Sparse Array in C! How accomplish it? Can I alloc only parts of an array?

Tags: c, arrays

The first question is: "How I do a simple sparse array in C (with one dimension only)?" {with my own hands, without libraries.}

And the last one: "Can I allocate only parts of an array?"

like *array;

then use malloc to allocate some mem for this;
so, We free the index that we don't want.

Can I do it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can I use it like an array? associativetree/hashtable[i]? is this more expensive in time our not?

Comment: A correctly constructed hash table has O(1) access time (unless the table gets very full or the hash is not well chosen). The constant multiplier will be larger than for a plain array, but...

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do it.

What you can do is to allocate blocks, but you need to design it carefully.

Probably the best optimization is to use ranges of cell. So you can use a linked list (or a map) of available ranges:

```
struct SparseBlock
{
  void *blockData;
  int beginIndex;
  int endIndex;
  struct SparseBlock *next;
}
```

obviously if `endIndex - beginIndex = 0` you have a single cell (that is isolated inside the array), otherwise you have got a block of cells, allowing you to allocate the right amount of memory for it.

This approach is simple for immutable sparse vectors, otherwise you should take care of

- restructuring the blocks whenever a hole is filled or generated
- just store single cells

In addition you have to decide how to index these blocks, you can keep them ordered in a linked list, or you can use a map to have a constant O(1) time to retrieve a n-th block (of course you will have to insert many equal keys for the same block if it's a range or reduce the index to the nearest lower index available).

Solutions are many, just express your creativity! :)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I was just suggesting you some ideas without any specific source.. maybe you can find something on the net, or just have fun and design it by yourself

Comment: Why do you use closed ranges? Half-open ranges are easier to manipulate and far more natural.

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to implement these in linked structures of one kind or another. In one dimension you can simple generate a linked list of occupied regions, and I've discussed [a two dimensional implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360156/initialize-2-d-array-of-unknown-size/1360185#1360185) in another context before.

You do lose O(1) access time this way, but the win on space can be considerable if the structure really is sparse.