# How to save memory in an array of which many elements are always 0?

Tags: c, tensor

I have a 2tensor in C that looks like:

```
int n =4;
int l =5;
int p =6;
int q=2;
```

I then initialize each element of T

```
//loop over each of the above indices
T[n][l][p][q]=...
```

However, many of them are zero and there are symmetries such as.

```
T[4][3][2][1]=-T[3][4][2][1]
```

1. How can I save memory on the elements of T which are zero? Ideally I would like to place something like `NULL` in those positions so they use 0 instead of 8 bytes. Also, later on in the calculation I can check if they are zero or not by checking if they are equal to `NULL`
2. How do I implicitly include those symmetries in T with using excess memory?

Edit: the symmetry can perhaps be fixed with a different implementation. But what about the zeros? Is there any implementation to not have them waste memory?

Comment: Arrays are stored in a consecutive memory guaranteed by the standard. So you can use `memset` to clear them.

Comment: Putting `NULL` or `0` in an array of integer still takes up the same amount of bytes even if it were not zero or NULL. You could initialize your array to be all zeros from the beginning. For the question on memory, it seems more of an implementation problem on how you represent your tensor, seeing as you said there are symmetries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I can think of something for the symmetry. But what about the zeros? Surely there's a way to implement this tensor with less memory.

Comment: it's called a [sparse array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2472608/995714). [Sparse matrix storage in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3470910/995714)

Comment: There's not really a way to answer the question without knowing more about the actual application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot influence the size of any variable by a value you write to it.
If you want to save memory you have not only to not use it, you have to not define a variable using it.
If you do not define a variable, then you have to not use it ever.
Then you have saved memory.
This is of course obvious.

Now, how to apply that to your problem.
Allow me to simplify, for one because you did not give enough information and explanation, at least not for me to understand every detail. For another, to keep the explanation simple.
So I hope that it suffices if I solve the following problem for you, which I think is kind of the little brother of your problem.

I have a large array in C (not really large, lets say N entries, with N==20).
But for special reasons, I will never need to actually read and write any even indices, they should act as if they contain 0, but I want to save the memory used by them.
So actually I want to only use M of the entries, with M*2==N.

So instead of

```
int Array[N]; /* all the theoretical elements */
```

I define

```
int Array[M]; /* only the actually used elements */
```

Of course I cannot access any of the elements which are not needed and it will not really be necessary.
But for the logic of my program, I want to be able to program as if I could access them, but be sure that they will always every only read 0 and ignore any written value.

So what I do is wrapping all accesses to the array.

```
int GetArray(int index)
{
    if (index & 1)
    {
        /* odd, I need to really access the array,
           but at a calculated index */
        return Array[index/2];
    } else
    {
        /* even, always 0 */
        return 0;
    }
}

void SetArray(int index, int value)
{
    if (index & 1)
    {
        /* odd, I need to really access the array,
           but at a calculated index */ */
        Array[index/2] = value;
    } else
    {
        /* even, no need to store anything, stays always "0" */
    }
}
```

So I can read and write as if the array were twice as large, but guarantee not to ever use the faked elements.
And by mapping the indices as
actualindex = wantindex / 2
I ensure that I do not access beyond the size of the actually existing array.

Porting this concept now to the more complicated setup you have described is your job. You know all the details, you can test wether everything works.

I recommend to extend GetArray() and SetArray() by checks on the resulting index, to make sure that it is never outside of the actual array.
You can also add all kinds of self checks to verify that all your rules and expectations are met.

Comment: That's a great idea and exactly what I was looking for. I suppose the GetArray and SetArray rules for my problem are more complicated but basically the same as what you suggested.