# Remove unnecessary value entries from multidimensional array in c?

Tags: arrays, c

Hi I am working with a scenario where user input multiple contiguous arrays of different lengths and I want to store these array for further use.

I am using multidimensional array for this purpose.
Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int rows,cols;
    
    printf("Enter the number of user input arrays ? ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    
    printf("Enter the maximum number of inputs in a single array ?"); //Need to remove these lines
    scanf("%d", &cols); //Need to remove these lines if possible
    
    int array[rows][cols];
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            array[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        int count;
        printf("Enter the number of inputs for array %d - ", i);
        scanf("%d",&count);
        for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    //// Use array for other purpose

    ////printf("\n\nArray --> \n");
    ////for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    ////{
        ////for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        ////{
            ////printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
        ////}
        ////printf("\n");
    ////}
    
    return 0;
}
```

Example input :

> Enter the number of user input arrays ? 5
> Enter the maximum number of inputs in a single array ?5
> Enter the number of inputs for array 0 - 5
> 1 2 6 3 5
> Enter the number of inputs for array 1 - 1
> 3
> Enter the number of inputs for array 2 - 2
> 6 5
> Enter the number of inputs for array 3 - 1
> 3
> Enter the number of inputs for array 4 - 1
> 9

Array created in this case :

> 1 2 6 3 5
> 3 0 0 0 0
> 6 5 0 0 0
> 3 0 0 0 0
> 9 0 0 0 0

Now I have number of issues in this case :

1. I want to reduce the space being used by removing the unnecessary entries in the array.
2. I would not like to use '0' or any other integer to define an unnecessary entry as it is a valid input.
3. I would like to remove the line

   printf("Enter the maximum number of inputs in a single array ?");
   scanf("%d", &cols);

Can anyone provide me help to overcome these issues.

Comment: This would require creating and re-creating arrays of pointers, each with capacities determined by the run-time user inputs. The only way to do this is with dynamic allocation of memory, using [c][m]alloc and maybe realloc.  Is this what you anticipated?

Comment: Why do not want the line `"Enter the maximum number of inputs in a single array ?"`  How would the user know what to do?

Comment: You might benefit from learning more about [sparse matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3470910/100770).

Comment: @ryyker So will it be like jagged array or something, where I will i just need to get the total arrays in first input and then based on user inputs decide the size of inner arrays.

Comment: @FredLarson - do sparse matrices provide run-time modification beyond initial definition?

Comment: @ryyker I want to remove the line as due to this, user needs to decide which of his array will take maximum space and what is that maximum space, which i need to avoid.

Comment: Once matrices are created, will they need to be modified again during the same run-time session?

Comment: @ryyker No, I will need to create it only once, I will only use the values, not update/create them

Comment: Then in that case I agree with Fred's comment that you should look into sparse matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the design criteria you have described:

- Array with user determined number of rows.
- Rows have differing lengths, also user determined.
- Reduce the space being used. (space only for real inputs, no padding, or filler values.)
- Array definition is created at run-time per user inputs, but is not required to change during same run-time session.

Note: One design criteria: `//Need to remove these lines if possible` is not included in this solution.  Without a description of the *desired* method to instruct user,  I do not know how to improve on the the user prompt method.

[Jagged arrays](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jagged-array-or-array-of-arrays-in-c-with-examples/) may be what you are looking for. Following is a simple example directly from the link that incorporates dynamic memory allocation that *can be adapted* to the code you have already discussed:

```
int main() 
{ 
    int rows;
    //Place you user input prompts and scans here
    
    // User input number of Rows 
    int* jagged[2];// 
  
    // Allocate memory for elements in row 0 
    jagged[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1); 
  
    // Allocate memory for elements in row 1 
    jagged[1] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3); 
  
    // Array to hold the size of each row 
    int Size[2] = { 1, 3 }, k = 0, number = 100; 
  
    // User enters the numbers 
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
  
        int* p = jagged[i]; 
  
        for (int j = 0; j < Size[k]; j++) { 
            *p = number++; 
  
            // move the pointer 
            p++; 
        } 
        k++; 
    } 
  
    k = 0; 
  
    // Display elements in Jagged array 
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
  
        int* p = jagged[i]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < Size[k]; j++) { 
  
            printf("%d ", *p); 
            // move the pointer to the next element 
            p++; 
        } 
        printf("\n"); 
        k++; 
        // move the pointer to the next row 
        jagged[i]++; 
    } 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

This is the concept moved a little closer to what I think you want, adapted from the code above to accept user input similar to what your code does...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;
    int i, j;
    
    int number = 100; 
    
    printf("Enter the number of user input arrays ? ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    
    // n Rows 
    int* jagged[rows]; 
    int Size[rows];//array to keep size if each array

    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the maximum number of inputs for array[%d]: ", i); 
        scanf("%d", &cols); //Need to remove these lines if possible

        // Allocate memory for elements in row 0 
        jagged[i] = malloc(sizeof(jagged[i]) * cols);
        Size[i] = cols;//set size of nth array
    }
    
    // User enters the numbers (This is spoofed.  You will need to code per comment below. 
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) { 
  
        int* p = jagged[i]; 
  
        for (j = 0; j < Size[i]; j++) { 
            *p = number++; //Note, this is spoofing user input .
                           //actual user input would be done exactly as above
                           //with printf prompts and scans for value
            // move the pointer 
            p++; 
        } 
    } 
  
    // Display elements in Jagged array 
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) { 
  
        int* p = jagged[i]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < Size[i]; j++) { 
  
            printf("%d ", *p); 
            // move the pointer to the next element 
            p++; 
        } 
        printf("\n"); 

        // move the pointer to the next row 
        jagged[i]++; 
    } 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This code is only valid for the compilers using C99, C11 or C18. It'll not work for the C89.

Comment: @Lucas - I am not sure what you would like me to do about that,  i.e. `C89` is not one of the criteria OP listed. And it is ancient, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No, no. Don't misinterpret it, pal. @ryyker I was just telling you that, I used to declare all variables up above in the listing. But you are using VLAs which are only supported after C99, so it just feels like we are coding in C++(although it is >=c99). _Declare before use._ Otherwise, you're answer is great.